# Unclear - Unsupported node-sass with current environment

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, node-sass, incompatibility

Trying to set up instance of [Facebook CTF](https://github.com/facebookarchive/fbctf) on an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04 and am running into the following error when doing the quick setup.

My current version of node-sass and node are

```
$ node -v
v15.4.0
$ npm node-sass -v
7.0.15
```

Interestingly, I get another vesion of node

```
$ npm node -v
7.0.15
```

The first two are supposedly compatible according to the Node Version Support Policy table on [GitHub](https://github.com/sass/node-sass). The node version 7.0.15 is not compatible with the version of node-sass.

However, when I run grunt, it indicates an unsupported environment.
Note: I have tried using individual sass commands and it works.

```
grunt --force
Loading "sass.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
>> For more information on which environments are supported please see:
>> https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.13.1
```

What I have tried/done-

1. Uninstall node-sass (include using -g, clear cache, remove package-lock.json) but oddly enough, node-sass does not get uninstalled.

Questions -

1. Why does the error log reference an older release of node-sass (v3.13.1)?
2. How do I reconcile versions?

Does it make a difference if some packages were installed as root user vs. regular user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Why was I getting the error?

1. Tracing package.json and package-locked.json files both indicate the older version
   "node-sass": "^3.7.0" and not the version I installed manually.

Solution -

1. uninstall node-sass, node
2. delete their node_module folders
3. run "npm install" to install any dependencies missing (node-sass and node)

Such that now when I check the versions installed, my output is as follow -

```
user@IP:/var/www/user# node -v
v6.17.1
user@IP:/var/www/user# npm node-sass -v
3.10.10
```

When reviewing the [Node Sass support policy table](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) on GitHub, these two versions are compatible. When I run grunt --force, there are no issues for node-sass.